# Android Google Maps Application - Mainactivity.java errors

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to develop my first application for Android with Google Maps V2. I've copied one code from this website: [source](http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step) and I followed the instructions step by step. Now I am getting these errors in my `Mainactivity` and I don't know what is wrong.

I have an error in the following lines:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

[image]

Mainactivity.java

```
package info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2;

import info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
        Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                  .position(CIU).title("My Office"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2"
                android:versionCode="1"
                android:versionName="1.0" >

                <uses-sdk
                    android:minSdkVersion="14"
                    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

                    <permission 
                    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
                    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

                <uses-feature
                    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                    android:required="true"/>

                <application
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                      <meta-data
                        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                        android:value="AIzaSyDciL7-T3BphxGv2q-A77vNrcyJQ_sTrgI"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                    <activity
                        android:name="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity"
                        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                </application>

            </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
import android.R;
```

and also you are missing a meta tag in manifest file

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You should have

```
import info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.R;
```

If it is same package no need to import

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As advised i removed `import android.R;` and put `import info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.R;` but it ask me to create new class R in package, and i have no idea how to do it

Comment: @anna also add the meta tag in application tag of manifest as suggested in my post. and also does it work?

Comment: thanks, i put the meta-data in my manifest, but i still don't know how to craete new class R in package.

Comment: @anna no need see if you have any errors in resources files. If so fix it. Clean and build the project you should see R.java under the gen folder

Comment: @anna any more errors. does it work? If you have errors pls specify the same

Comment: no more errors. After the changes that you suggested and clean and build the project doesn't have any other errors. But when i want to run it on the real device, my phone doesn't appear on the list. I guess i need to check the target.

Comment: @anna yes. one more thing that is missing in your code is You are not checking for the availability of google play services. Google maps need google play services. Most real devices have one. You need to install the apk on real device

Comment: i had google play services instaled on my mobile but i updated it :) but the application doesn't work, please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207970/android-application-doesnt-work