# Android application doesn't work

Tags: android

Copied the android code from http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step This is the application that use Google Maps v2. I generated my Api key and run the application. When i run the application on the real device the application has some problems and i can see the message: Your application has stoped unexpectedly. 
I have attached the code and logCat.

Mainactivity.java

```
package info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2;

import info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
        Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                  .position(CIU).title("My Office"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2"
                android:versionCode="1"
                android:versionName="1.0" >

                <uses-sdk
                    android:minSdkVersion="14"
                    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

                    <permission 
                    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
                    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
                <uses-permission 
                    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

                <uses-feature
                    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                    android:required="true"/>

                <application
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                      <meta-data
                        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                        android:value="AIzaSyDciL7-T3BphxGv2q-A77vNrcyJQ_sTrgI"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                    <activity
                        android:name="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity"
                        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                </application>

            </manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
01-18 18:55:11.437: W/dalvikvm(9874): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11035: Linfo/tekguc/umut/googlemapsmapsandroidv2/MainActivity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
01-18 18:55:11.437: D/dalvikvm(9874): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
01-18 18:55:11.437: D/dalvikvm(9874): VFY: dead code 0x000b-0045 in Linfo/tekguc/umut/googlemapsmapsandroidv2/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
01-18 18:55:11.445: I/ApplicationPackageManager(9874): cscCountry is not German : XEC
01-18 18:55:11.460: W/dalvikvm(9874): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2/info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     ... 11 more
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2-1.apk]
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-18 18:55:11.476: E/AndroidRuntime(9874):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2-1.apk] Do you try to run it on emulator?

Comment: @piotrpo no, i haven't try on emulator as i don't have the google play services installed.

Comment: @piotrpo is there any way i can make it working on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use simple javascript as alternative like this.

write this code on notepad and save as html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Animations</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
// The following example creates a marker in location1, location2
// using a DROP animation. Clicking on the marker will toggle
// the animation between a BOUNCE animation and no animation.


var location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.298716, 112.766686);
var location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.298716, 112.766868);
var marker;
var map;
var image = 'marks.png';
var info;
var data = '<div id="content">'+
'</div>'+
'<h1 id="first" class="first">Your Title </h1>'+
'<div id="body">'+
'<p>type your body here'+
'</p>'+
'<p><a href="link">Read More...</a></p>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>';

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: location1
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:true,
    icon: image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: location2
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {

  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
    info.close();
  } else {
  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: data 
  }).open(map, marker);

  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

insert html into assets folder, then use `webview` in `activity_main.xml`

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

hopefully can help. Sorry for my english